CPT meta values intermittently return empty
I have a parent CPT (Form) and a child CPT (Registration).
Form A currently has around 3,000 child registration posts. Am showing them on a custom admin table, 20 posts per page. The table columns show various meta values (say reg_name, reg_email).
Am encountering the following error: Around every 1-2 hours, for around 10-15 minutes, all the meta values are empty. Then they show well again, only for the issue to reappear later.
During this downtime, when testing retrieving registration post meta values, they return empty. After the downtime, they work well.
get_post_meta( $reg_post->ID, 'reg_name', true ); // Returns: ""

$reg_post->reg_name; // Returns: ""

get_post_meta( $reg_post->ID ) // Returns: []

Looked in the database and the meta values are always there, including in the downtime.
There is a Form B which has around 100 registration posts. The issue does not happen there, even when Form A is in downtime.
What could be causing this issue?

are you sure that $reg_post->ID has a valid value? Have you confirmed this directly by looking at it? Sometimes get_post and other functions that return WP_Post objects return a false or null value but most people never bother to check for this and assume it always works. Has your PHP error log said anything about this? Where is $reg_post coming from? WP_Post doesn't normally have a reg_name member variable, can you share more of the code?

@TomJNowell Yes, I verified that the $reg_post->ID has a valid value. I also tested using directly a reg post int ID, get_post_meta( 123 );, and it also returns [] during the downtime.

how are the meta values set, and how is $reg_post retrieved? Can you share more code? There's not enough information to diagnose this problem and write an answer. Do you have caching systems in place?

@TomJNowell The server is on WP Engine, which does have caching systems. The posts are retrieved using a new WP_Query( $args ) call. The meta values are added during a wp_insert_post() call.

WP Engine shouldn't make an impact here, can you edit the question to include the smallest version of the code that reproduces the problem? Avoid descriptions, nothing you've described sounds out of the ordinary but it also doesn't explain much. Without seeing how the query is created, the main loop etc, all we have is generic WP guesswork
